# How do I specify YAML array index numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, yaml

Please excuse my first post. So I got a RapidAPI for Covid-19 updates set up and properly spouting it's results to the console as an array JSON as the following: [YAML Array Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svxfN.png) Now, I want to be able to list specific countries and their following info from the JSON array using fetch and  inner HTML method from the JSON array above.
So, I tried to use

`document.getElementById('countryname').innerHTML = response.0.country;`
which returns an error. But each country is defined under their own tables using numbers 0 to 232.

So I tried
`document.getElementById('countryname').innerHTML = response.country[0];` but it returns as *"Cannot read property '0' of undefined."* I looked everywhere for the solution and I'm stumped. response.country by itself also turns up as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's

```js
response[0].country
```

or even:

```js
response[0]['country']
```

I suggest you read the [Array documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to understand how they work

Answer (score 0):

looks like `response` is an Array so you can index each individual element of this array with `reponse[index]` so for the first element `reponse[0]`

each response item has a "country" property then so you should be able to access this as
`reponse[0].country`

Comment: Using reponse[0].country;
returns "cannot read property 'country' of undefined"

and

reponse[0].country;
returns "response is not defined"

Comment: could you post the code how you retrieve the api response? 
If your  `response` object is not defined my first guess would be that the API call is asynchronous and you have to wait for it to be loaded before accessing the response. 
Can't tell without the rest of the surrounding code.